# Rake: says table doesn't exist when I try to migrate.... no duh, it doesn't exist, that's why I'm trying to migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Command and trace:

```
% rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test --trace
(in /Users/lprestonsegoiii/Work/GravityLabs/TinderBox)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Mysql::Error: Table 'project.medias' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `medias`
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:221:in `log'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:323:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:470:in `columns'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1301:in `columns'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1314:in `column_names'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.5.6/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/ordering.rb:33:in `ordering_condition_details'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.5.6/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/ordering.rb:25:in `create_condition'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.5.6/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/or_conditions.rb:28:in `create_condition'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.5.6/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/column_conditions.rb:63:in `respond_to?'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1511:in `respond_to?'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.4.0/lib/paperclip.rb:402:in `attachment_definitions'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.4.0/lib/paperclip.rb:283:in `has_attached_file'
/project/app/models/media.rb:23
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in `require_or_load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:425:in `load_missing_constant'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
project/test/factories/general.rb:87  #This is where Media is referenced... but it should have errored about any of the other 10 Models that don't have tables above where this one is used in this file....
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:147:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:147:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-2.0.5/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:20:in `find_definitions'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-2.0.5/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-2.0.5/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `find_definitions'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-2.0.5/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-2.0.5/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-2.0.5/lib/factory_girl/rails2.rb:6
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:614:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:614:in `after_initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:613:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:613:in `after_initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:179:in `process'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/project/config/environment.rb:17   #why does it jump into the env? this is irrelevant to raking.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin//rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin//rake:19
```

EDIT:
the first migration file:
http://pastebin.com/49aJe2wv
the table it's erroring on doesn't even exist yet.

there are no tables in the test db.

EDIT2: Detail on the stack trace
factories/general:87

```
Factory.define :media, :class => Media do |m| #line 87 <----
  m.name "Alice is in an asian wonderland"
  m.document_file_name "alice_test_image.jpeg"
  m.document_content_type "image/jpeg"
  m.document_file_size "155548"
...
end
```

EDIT3:
Media.rb
http://pastebin.com/rZpdBTyq

Comment: I think we need to see the contents of the migration file that it is trying to run.

Comment: if you say so. I don't think it will help, since the table it's erring on isn't even in the first migration.

Comment: also, the stack trace doesn't show that it's getting to any of the migrations....

Comment: You're no doubt having a problem with transactions. Try breaking this up into several migrations... Later: looking over your code and the error, that's probably not what's happening. Where is that "medias" stuff?

Comment: in the general file in the factories folder. I'll post that, too.

Comment: @DerNalia - pastebins are temporary, and StackOverflow is forever. I can no longer see your pastebin... if I'm having a similar problem and stumble over your question, I can't see for sure if I've got the same issue. Would you please paste in the actual migration code?

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a problem with your factory, or perhaps factory_girl/factory_girl_rails.

factory_girl_rails loads all your factories at boot time, and I think if they include associations, validations etc, then ActiveModel/ActiveRecord gets called to inspect the models.  Of course in this case they find that there is no database to inspect.

I had the same problem, and the solution/workaround is to remove the gem 'factory_girl_rails' and replace it with plain 'factory_girl', and then load the factories manually in `spec_helper`:

```
require 'factory_girl'
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you're running your db:migrate task in your test environment and your factory plugin is trying to load models for tables that don't exist yet:

/Users/lprestonsegoiii/Work/GravityLabs/TinderBox/test/factories/general.rb:87

You should run your migration on your development db and then use db:test:prepare to clone the database for tests:

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: both give the same error =\ I think all rake commands give this error. I don't think it's related to migrations.

Comment: Can you post your Media model?  Perhaps something there is trying to load all the Media on class load or something else.  If you can find that and disable it you can run your migrations.

Answer (score 0):

First off, we need to see all of your migrations. Chances are that you deleted a migration or modified it after it was created, which leads to this kind of behaviour (or if you did not use scaffolding to generate the migrations, then perhaps you wrote them incorrectly).

In this case, it is probably trying to run a migration that modifies the table, but there is no migration run before that which actually creates that table, leading to the error you see.

Comment: Stacktrace does not show any migrations being run, or attempted to be run. If you read the stack trace, the Media table is referenced in the factories folder. ... which makes no sense, because there is no reason for rake db:migrate to go into that folder.